# Get Install File for Already Installed RPM

Tags: rpm

I would like to install this custom package, `packageA`, onto another Linux box.

```
$yum list installed | grep packageA
packageA.x86_64
```

But, I don't have access to the installation file, i.e. `packageA` only exists on this box.

How can I do this?

Comment: you might try transporting it by way of tar file: `tar cpf custom-package.tar $(rpm -ql <packageName>)` Might still run into problems, though, since applications often times create files after installation that aren't in the package database. Some of the configuration files also may have host-specific information in it.

Comment: `rpm -qi packageA` could tell you where to get it from.

Comment: @JoelDavis That creates a tarball, which you'd still have to convert to a rpm.

Comment: @Gilles, aware of that, which is why my comment refers to it as such. Also, OP never stated the package on the other system needed to be an rpm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Rpmrebuild](http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net/) is a tool to build an RPM file from a package that has already been installed.

(I found it by looking for an rpm equivalent to `dpkg-repack`, which I knew about.)

Comment: can that be installed via `yum`? I tried to install by downloading the `rpm`, but then there were missing dependencies that I couldn't find.

Comment: @Kevin If your distribution carries it, you can do `yum install rpmrebuild`. If not, you need to find an rpm *for your distribution* (just because two distributions use rpm as the package format doesn't mean all packages can be installed on both, e.g. because the package names are different which causes dependencies to be different). If you can't find an rpm for your distribution, built it from source.